# .getMonth and .getYear etc. won't extract correctly from dates in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have dates stored in a column of a Google Sheet and I want to extract parts of the dates such as year and month. I tried to follow examples I have found but they do not work. Here is the code:

```
var analysisSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var analysisSheet = analysisSS.getSheetName();
var monthsListRange = analysisSS.getRangeByName(MonthDateRange);
var monthsList = monthsListRange.getValues();
var monthPointer = 1;
var monthCode = monthsList[monthPointer].getMonth();
```

Which produces the error message:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getMonth in object Sun Jan 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST).DetailsDismiss

This is the correct date stored in the first cell of the spreadsheet column.

Comment: use proper tags, if you want answers. Take the [tour]

Comment: `monthsList[monthPointer][0].getMonth();`

Comment: As suggested above use a double index because getValues returns a 2D array.